# How to use wget with headers in liveness probe in a yaml file in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, datadog

I am trying to use **wget** in my liveness probe in Kubernetes. Here is the code:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: test
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "99999999"
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - wget
        - -O- 
        - --header=
        - "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde"
        - --header= 
        - "DD-API-KEY: a123456"
        - https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/1234567 | grep \"overall_state\":\"OK\"
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
```

But I am facing the following error when I use **describe** command in the pod:

```
Liveness probe failed: wget: bad port ' abcde'
```

My goal is to check an alert in Datadog. If the alert is red the pod will restart.

The **wget** command works in the terminal. It looks like the YAML file is facing some problems using the headers.

Comment: Why are you splitting an argument `--header="DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde"`  into separate lines? It treats "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde" as a separate argument and intreprets it as a hostname with a port separated by a `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the equal sign from the `--header=` and use `--header` instead

```
        command:
        - wget
        - -O-
        - --header
        - "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: abcde"
        - --header
        - "DD-API-KEY: a123456"
        - https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/1234567
        - -q
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
```

Note that using wget in a liveness probe can cause unnecessary load on the system. Instead, it's recommended to use a more lightweight command like `curl` or `nc` to check the health of your application. See this [link](https://spacelift.io/blog/kubernetes-liveness-probe)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the simple way to rewrite this:

```
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - 'wget -O- ...'
```